# Setup different version of python in virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I am trying to install a different version of python in my virtual environment. I have python 3.6.5 installed in my local but would want version 3.4 in this new virtual environment.

I tried doing

```
virtualenv -p python3.4 newenv
```

But it throws an error

> The path python3.4 (from --python=python3.4) does not exist

Could anyone assist. I am trying to do it on a Linux machine.

Comment: You need to install that version of python to create an environment for it

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, your path isn't correct. Maybe provide the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have python3.4 installed on your machine?

If so specify full path. For example: virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.4 newenv

Comment: Then you will need to install it on your local machine.